Sphere - Cube overlap : None, Partial, or Full?
In order to represent spheres with octal trees, I need to determine overlaps between spheres and axis-aligned cubes. More specifically, there are three cases :

The cube is completely inside the sphere. We mark it as full.
The cube is completely outside the sphere. We mark it as empty.
The cube is partially inside the sphere. We subdivide it and recurse.

Here is my current best guess as to how to do it.
I'm asking here to know if there are any simpler ways (meaning lesser complexity / fewer operations)
Thanks to an answer to this previous question, I found this algorithm to detect any overlap. However, it is not able to distinguish between the cube being fully inside the sphere, or just partially.
According to suggestions given here, I'm first checking for total overlap by checking whether the furthest corner of the cube is inside the sphere. If it isn't, then we use Jim Arvo's algorithm to determine if there is any overlap at all.
So here is what I came up with : (using c23)
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#include <math.h>

/* A 3D point with type-punning to access coordinates by name or index */
typedef union point_3d {
    struct {
        GLdouble x, y, z;
    } coord;

    GLdouble t[ 3 ];
} point_3d;

/* An axis-aligned cube */
typedef struct cube {
    /* corner with smallest coordinates */
    point_3d p_min;

    /* side length */
    GLdouble len;
} cube_t;

typedef struct sphere {
    unsigned int radius;
    point_3d center;
} sphere_t;

/* Clearly defined values for our result */
typedef enum overlap {
    no_overlap = -1,
    partial_overlap = 0,
    total_overlap = 1,
} overlap_t;

static inline GLdouble sq( GLdouble val ) {
    return val * val;
}

static bool point_in_sphere( point_3d p, struct sphere s ) {
    GLdouble dx = p.t[ 0 ] - s.center.t[ 0 ];
    GLdouble dy = p.t[ 1 ] - s.center.t[ 1 ];
    GLdouble dz = p.t[ 2 ] - s.center.t[ 2 ];
    return sq( s.radius ) >= sq( dx ) + sq( dy ) + sq( dz );
}

overlap_t cube_overlaps_sphere( cube_t c, sphere_t s ) {
    point_3d p_min = c.p_min;
    point_3d p_max = { .t= {
        p_min.t[0] + c.taille,
        p_min.t[1] + c.taille,
        p_min.t[2] + c.taille,
    } };
    point_3d c_centre = { .t = { 
        p_min.t[0] + c.taille / 2,
        p_min.t[1] + c.taille / 2, 
        p_min.t[2] + c.taille / 2,
    } };
    point_3d v = { .t = {
        c_centre.t[ 0 ] - s.centre.t[ 0 ],
        c_centre.t[ 1 ] - s.centre.t[ 1 ],
        c_centre.t[ 2 ] - s.centre.t[ 2 ],}
    };
    point_3d far_corner = { .t = { 
        v.t[ 0 ] < 0 ? p_min.t[ 0 ] : p_max.t[ 0 ],
        v.t[ 1 ] < 0 ? p_min.t[ 1 ] : p_max.t[ 1 ],
        v.t[ 2 ] < 0 ? p_min.t[ 2 ] : p_max.t[ 2 ],
    } };

    if ( point_in_sphere( far_corner, s ) ) {
        return total_overlap;
    }

    /* Algorithm by Jim Arvo */
    GLdouble dmin = 0;
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        if ( s.center.t[ i ] < p_min.t[ i ] ) {
            dmin += pow( s.center.t[ i ] - p_min.t[ i ], 2 );
        } else if ( s.center.t[ i ] > p_max.t[ i ] ) {
            dmin += pow( s.center.t[ i ] - p_max.t[ i ], 2 );
        }
    }
    if ( dmin <= pow( s.radius, 2 ) ) {
        return partial_overlap;
    } else {
        return no_overlap;
    }
}


Subtract the center of the cube from the center of the sphere. (This gives the vector from the sphere center to the cube center.) Take the signs of the vector components. Those indicate which corner of the cube is farthest from the center of the sphere and which is closest. Test those.

Do not use pow(something, 2). Just multiply the operand by itself. It is faster and may be more accurate.

Do not take the square root to get a distance to compare it to the radius of the sphere. Just compare distances by comparing their squares. Again, this is faster.

@EricPostpischil To clarify, I should replace the first part with your suggestion, then use Jim Arvo's algorithm if that corner is outside the sphere ?

"Is there a better way than this?" is pretty broad for an SO question, and to the extent that it affords the possibility of multiple answers pointing out different improved alternatives, it's not well suited to this site.  Supposing that the code presented works (to the best of your knowledge), Code Review SE might be a better fit.

@JohnBollinger I understand that may be true, however I admit to posting here regardless because of the staggering difference in activity. In my (admittedly limited) experience, posts there get significantly fewer to no responses at all.

What does your algorithm report when all the corners of the cube are outside the sphere because the cube completely contains the sphere?

@EricPostpischil It is supposed to report partial_overlap because only part of the cube is in the sphere. What matters here it the perspective of the cube

The number of operations required to compute your overlap parameter scales linearly in the number of spacial dimensions.  For any particular numbers of dimensions, it is O(1).  The strategy that yields the fewest operations for some sphere, cube pairs will be different than that for some other pairs, so best strategy overall for a given application will probably be the one that is best for the largest number of cases tested.  For your particular application, I anticipate that that will be the partial overlap case, because it is near the surface of the sphere that you will be branching most deeply.
The Avro algorithm you have incorporated computes the shortest distance from the center of the sphere to any part of the solid cube (corner, edge, face, or interior), and compares that to the sphere's radius to determine whether there is any overlap.  It is effective and efficient.  I don't see a way to improve on that for the job it does.
Avro does not distinguish between partial and complete overlap of the cube, whereas you need to do.  Courtesy of @EricPostpischil, however, we have the observation that if the corner of the cube most distant from the center of the sphere is in or on the surface of the sphere, then the cube is completely encompassed, otherwise not, and also that we can determine which corner that is from the vector from sphere center to cube center.  It turns out that a variation on that computation can be structured analogously enough to the Avro algorithm to combine the two in the same loop.  That might look like so:
overlap_t compute_overlap(cube_t cube, sphere_t sphere) {
    GLdouble d2min = 0;    // minimum sq distance from the center of the sphere to any part of the cube
    GLdouble d2max = 0;    // maximum sq distance from the center of the sphere to [a corner of] the cube

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        GLdouble delta = sphere.center[i] - cube.pmin[i];

        if (delta < cube.len / 2) {
            // the sphere center is on the decreasing side of the cube center
            d2max += sq(delta - cube.len);
            if (delta < 0) {
                 // the sphere center is on the decreasing side of the whole cube
                 d2min += sq(delta);
            }
        } else {
            // the sphere center is on the increasing side of the cube center
            d2max += sq(delta);
            if (delta > cube.len) {
                 // the sphere center is on the increasing side of the whole cube
                d2min += sq(delta - cube.len);
            }
        }
    }

    if (sq(sphere.radius) <= d2min) {
        return no_overlap;
    } else if (sq(sphere.radius) < d2max) {
        return partial_overlap;
    } else {
        return total_overlap;
    }
}

I can't prove that that is optimal for your case, and especially not that there are no minor rearrangements that your particular compiler's optimizer might find more pleasing.  I do, however, think that modulo such minor micro-optimizations, you're going to have trouble doing better for your case.

Very well done ! I didn't think about combining the two algorithms in one loop. The only micro-optimisation I can see right away is computing cube.len / 2 once before the loop, but it is obvious enough that the compiler might already do that.

I've looked through a few examples and this seems to work. I'm accepting this answer as correct

I added your name and links to both this post and Arvo's original algorithm to my code, above your function. It's going into some (ungraded) college work of mine.
